# How Can I Loop Each Value through an Imported CSV File?

Tags: python, list, loops, csv

Just started using Python this past week and I really like it! However, I'm stuck trying to figure out how to read a csv file through a loop. Looking through this example provided by https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm:

```
fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'mango']
for fruit in fruits:
    print('Current fruit :', fruit)
```

How can I properly replace the 
    ['banana', 'apple',  'mango']
with the csv file in such a way that it prints the same way as shown above?

```
import csv

with open(r'C:\Documents\Fruits.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    fruit_list = list(reader)


fruits = [fruit_list]
for fruit in fruits:
    print('Current fruit :', fruit)
```

But it instead prints:

Current fruit : [['banana'], ['apple'], ['mango']]

Thanks

Comment: Remove the square brackets from `fruits = [fruit_list]`

Comment: fruit_list is already list. Lose the square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fruit_list` was a list of lists. When you perform `fruits = [fruit_list]` you transformed `fruit_list` from `[['banana'], ['apple'], ['mango']]` to `[[['banana'], ['apple'], ['mango']]]`.This is list of lists of lists. Instead, you want to turn your list of lists into a simple list. This will do:

```
fruits = [i for I in fruit_list for i in I]

for fruit in fruits:
    print('Current fruit :', fruit)
```

Good luck learning Python !

Comment: Thank you, that works! But why does the output still retain the brackets and quotes shown here: Current fruit : ['banana']
Current fruit : ['apple']
Current fruit : ['mango']

Comment: Didn't notice that `fruit_list` got imported as a list of lists. I'll edit to fix that.